# iPhone number forwarding trackable

Tags: iphone, tracking

I have an iPhone4s that is set up to call forward to my iphone7. The 4s is turned off and doesn't ring but is the iPhone7's number traceable/trackable when being forwarded from the 4s?

More information:

the call forwarding is set up on the iPhone4s it is not set up by the carrier/exchange

the iPhone4s is off and the calls do forward when 4s is off.

Who knows or who can find out (track/trace) the phone number bring forwarded to (iPhone7 phone number)?

Comment: The phone is set up to forward, or your number at the phone company exchange is set to forward? If your 4S is off, I suspect the latter (which makes your title misleading). What kind of 'trace/track' are you talking about? I think you need to add a few more details.

Comment: You say "the call forwarding is set up on the iPhone4s it is not set up by the carrier/exchange" .  But you also say "The 4s is turned off ".    There is a big misunderstanding on your part.  If the 4s really *IS* turned off then the carrier/exchange *IS* where it is all happening.... no ifs, no buts ... its a fact.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the new information, your call is being forwarded by the phone company that has the number for the iPhone 4s.

So they have the information. Who they give this information to, that's up to them.